# Fully delete abandoned commit from Gerrit DB AND 'query'

Tags: sql, lucene, gerrit

I am trying to fully purge a change from Gerrit and running into some problems.

Previously I tried to follow this guide to achieve my goal:

https://www.onyxpoint.com/deleting-abandoned-commits-from-gerrit-code-review/

I messed this up however, and somehow managed to do the following:

- Purge the offending change-id from all the tables in the Gerrit gsql database
- The change still appears in the web-interface, but if I click on it, it fires an error: "The page you requested was not found, or you do not have permission to view this page."
- If I run 'gerrit query' for the change, it still shows up, replete with all information.

Where is the change information coming from if it is not in the DB??? I also tried flushing all caches.  Is it somewhere in the search index for lucene or something?

This is not super important, but it is really driving me nuts!

Comment: Have you run the [reindex command](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/pgm-reindex.html) to update the Lucene index?

Comment: @MagnusBäck Thank you!! This indeed solved the issue. Howevever, the doc page you linked to doesn't quite work as-is with v2.9.  I had to do the following to get it to work:  `$ gerrit.sh stop; java -jar path/to/gerrit.war reindex  -d gerrit_site; gerrit.sh start`.   BTW If you reply as an answer I'll approve.

Comment: As of [gerrit 2.14](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.14.md#Delete-Changes), _Delete Change_ implements this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries use Gerrit's secondary index (by default Lucene-based) so if you modify the database outside of Gerrit you have to reindex the data with the [reindex command](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/pgm-reindex.html):

```
$ java -jar path/to/gerrit.war reindex -d path/to/gerrit-site-dir
```

This command should only be executed when Gerrit isn't running.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I didn't have to perform a re-index. But an additional step(5):

1. Open the GSQL interface

   ```
   $ gerrit-cli gsql
   ```
2. The following command will mark the change set as a draft change set in the Gerrit database.

   ```
   gerrit> update changes set status='d' where change_id='64581';
   ```
3. Next, update the associated patch sets.

   ```
   gerrit> update patch_sets set draft='Y' where change_id='64581';
   gerrit> \q
   ```
4. Prior to making further changes, you need to make sure that the Gerrit caches have been flushed. If you don’t do this, you may end up with strange
   results when using the Web UI in relation to this change set.

   ```
   $ gerrit-cli flush-caches --cache changes
   ```
5. Ensure that the administrator has "View Drafts" and "Delete Drafts" permission on the repo for refs/*
    [image]
6. Finally, delete the patch set(s) that you had previously abandoned.
   In this case, we’re going to assume that you have two patch sets to
   delete.

   ```
   $ gerrit-cli review 64581,1 --delete
   $ gerrit-cli review 64581,2 --delete
   ```

   Deleting each patch-set one by one can be a PITA. Nuke 'em in one go using the GUI:
   [image]

Comment: Also run 'git gc' in gerrit to ensure the blob gets removed from gerrits git, else it's still browseble via gitweb.

Comment: Other way to run gsql command: `java -jar gerrit.war gsql -d <SITE_PATH>`